# Does Oracle use steal/no-force approach?

Tags: database, oracle, undo, redo

I already googled hours for his, but I just can't find any information about this. 
It says everywhere that steal/no-force is the most common approach for database systems, but without proof I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle uses a steal/ no-force approach.  Blocks can be written to disk before the changes in those blocks have been committed (because the changes are protected by UNDO).  And changed blocks do not need to be written to disk before the transaction can be committed (because the changes are protected by REDO).